How can I add a "Open Powershell Here as SYSTEM" command to my context menu that will open to the current directory as NT Authority\SYSTEM?
I have the following registry entry that creates a context menu to open a powershell shell as admin at the current directory:
"%bin%\Elevator" -dir "%V" -elev high pwsh -noexit
Elevator is a utility found here.
But it doesn't provide the option to elevate to SYSTEM.
I'm aware of nircmd and I use it to run Regedit as system like this:
nircmd.exe elevatecmd runassystem regedit.exe, but I'm not sure how to use it to open Pwsh to the current directory.
Does anyone know of a solution?
Any help greatly appreciated!

Save the content bellow as a .reg file and execute it to create context menu.
You have to put Nircmd.exe in your Windows directory.
Then, when you right click on a folder, you will have "PowerShell System Prompt" in your context menu
It works on my Windows 10, I think that Windows 11 context menu is not managed in the same way
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Folder\Shell\SystemPosh]
@="PowerShell System Prompt"
"icon"="\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe\""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Folder\Shell\SystemPosh\Command]
@="nircmd.exe elevatecmd runassystem powershell -noexit -command \"&{Set-Location '%1'}\""

